# Why can't I use the selenium.(etc...) library?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When I try to use the selenium. library to perform commands, they don't work. 
I've imported the import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*; library but I get a java: can't find symbol error.

```
    selenium.open("http://google.com/");

    String allLinks[]=selenium.getAllLinks();
    for(int i=0;i<allLinks.length;i++){

        selenium.click(allLinks[i]);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Comment: Did you try adding the Selenium jars to the build path of your project?

Comment: Try to delete .class file of your project and recompile the code.

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct libraries? selenium.getAllLinks() is not part of selenium. looks like some other